# Re-append list items after jQuery slice and remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, html-lists, detach

I made a unordered list that randomizes its list items, of which I only want to show 5 on normal screen sizes and 3 on smaller screen sizes.

By using the jQuery [slice()](https://api.jquery.com/slice/%22slice()%22) function I remove the other list items based on window size.

However, after reaching <650px window size (where it slices to 3 items), I can't seem to re-append the removed list items when going back to >650px window size. 
I tried to use the [detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/%22detach()%22) function but can't get it to work so far.

This is my code:

```
function showHide() {
    var displayDefaultLarge = $("ul li").slice(5);
    var displayDefaultSmall = $("ul li").slice(3);

    var insertLarge = displayDefaultLarge;

    if ($(window).width() < 650) {
        insertLarge = displayDefaultSmall.detach();
    } else {
        insertLarge.appendTo("ul");
        insertLarge.detach();
    }
}

showHide();

$(window).resize(function() {
    showHide();
});
```

A Jsfiddle to show what's going wrong can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/ccmrfb4z/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ? Why do you call `.detach()` after `.appendTo()` at `else` ?

Comment: I have just added a jsfiddle. I called them in that order because it showed all list items otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `:lt()`, `:gt()` selectors ; `.show()`, `.hide()`

```
    function showHide() {

        if ($(window).width() < 650) {
            $("ul li:gt(2)").hide();
        } else {
            $("ul li:lt(5)").show();
        }
    }

    $("ul li").slice(5).remove();

    showHide();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        showHide();
    });
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ccmrfb4z/1/

Comment: Your answer led me to the solution. I added the following before the `showHide();`: `$("ul li").slice(5).remove();` to remove the unneeded list items after randomizing. I'll add this to your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

one option, instead of using javascript is to use css media queries:-

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
}

/* standard - show 5 */
li:nth-child(n+6) {
  display: none;
}

/* less than 650 - show 3 */
@media (max-width: 650px) {
  li:nth-child(n+4) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
      </div>
      <p>Name</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
      </div>
      <p>Name</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
      </div>
      <p>Name</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
      </div>
      <p>Name</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
      </div>
      <p>Name</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
      </div>
      <p>Name</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
      </div>
      <p>Name</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
      </div>
      <p>Name</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
      </div>
      <p>Name</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
      </div>
      <p>Name</p>
    </a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Because I need to randomize the order of the list items first I can't use CSS media queries. These will hide the list items before Javascript can randomize their order.

Comment: if you randomise the order then this should still work.